# need to read BOOT0 pin on STM32H725

Tags: stm32, bootloader, stm32h7

I have designed a set of boards for a client with one USB interface to the main controller.  We can bootload it by the usual methods, and bootload the CPUs on the other boards by pass-thru from the main controller.  I send coded messages to the main controller which properly toggles BOOT0 and nRESET on the downstream boards and then goes into pure passthru.

So far, we have always toggled the BOOT0 pin to the main controller to signal when to exit pass-thru mode.  Always worked, no problem.

We have a new version using an STM32H725.   I now find that it has a dedicated BOOT0 pin.   Prior CPUs always had the BOOT0 pin mapped to a GPIO pin, so that we could read it to exit pass-thru, but I can't do that now.

I have dug around hoping to find something in a SYSCFG register to read the BOOT0 pin, but no luck.

Am I totally shot here, or is there any trick to read a dedicated BOOT0 pin that isn't mapped to GPIO?   If I can't do this, it will have to get messy (embedded escape codes in the data stream...yuk.)

Thanks in advance and happy new year!

Jeff Casey  /  Rockfield Research Inc.

Comment: I have found on multiple occasions that that STM32 are always "pin-compatible", except for the pins they wanted to change!  It looks like you might be unlucky :-(.

Comment: Connect this pin to another GPIO.